# Filter two arrays with nested objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript

My use case: I have a two arrays one called "name" and the other called "customer". I need to extract the customers from the names list and get a new array called "lead".

```js
const name = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "smith"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "john"
}]

const customer = [{
  id: 1,
  name: {
    id: 1,
    name: "smith"
  }
}]
```

I am expecting to get

```
lead = [{
  id: 2,
  name: "john"
}]
```

the code I am using is

```js
const name = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "smith"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "john"
}]

const customer = [{
  id: 1 a,
  name: {
    id: 1,
    name: "smith"
  }
}]


const lead = name.filter(({
  id: id1
}) => !customer.some(({
  "name.id": id2
}) => id2 === id1));
console.log(lead);
```

This works if the data is flat, but when I use it with nested objects I get the full "name" list.

**Working final code below**

While Farrukh Normuradov answer does work, I used Pilchard's answer in the comments. I also fixed a typo.

Final code

`const lead = name.filter(({  id: id1 }) => !customer.some(({  name: {id: id2} }) => id2 === id1));`

Comment: Why are you expecting to get this object? Can you further clarify your selection criteria?

Comment: So, `lead`s are `name`s that are not `customer`s?

Comment: I get a syntax error when I run your code, not the full "name" list. You have the right idea, using `filter` and `!``some`, I just think you have some syntax problems around "name.id".

Comment: your destructuring in your `some()` call is incorrect, it should be `{ name: {id: id2} }` ( and the typo Mister JoJo mentioned)

Comment: @crawlings did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `filter`, `map` and `includes`.

```js
const user_list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "smith"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "john"
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "timur"
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "igor"
},]

const customers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: {
        id: 1,
        name: "smith"
    }
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: {
        id: 4,
        name: "igor"
    }
}]

const leads = user_list.filter(user => !customers.map(customer => customer.id).includes(user.id))

console.log(leads);
```

Comment: The OP's use of `some()` is more efficient than `map()`ing the entire customers array as it will return as soon as it finds a match. The only problem with their code was their use of destructuring.